# Script for adding date when data is entered into specific columns?

Tags: date, google-sheets, automation

Total n00b here. I'm trying to make my google sheet automatically add dates when dat gets entered into specific columns. I've found the script below that'll let me check 1 column but is there a way to make it check, for example, columns 3 and 6 and add the dates in  the column to the left?

Thanks for your help.

I've tried entering the the same script with a different COLUMNTOCHECK and making a second script. My hope was that it would check both columns and return the date that the data was entered in each column.

```
//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 8;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,-1];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'LHe ontvangst/retour'

function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
// CORE VARIABLES
// The columns you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNS_TO_CHECK = [3, 6];
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0, -1];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = 'LHe ontvangst/retour';

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  // Checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME) {
    var col = selectedCell.getColumn();
    
    // Checks if the edited column is in the list of columns to check.
    if (COLUMNS_TO_CHECK.indexOf(col) !== -1) {
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0], DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Franco Vera. It works perfectly. :)